# ElasticSearch nodes after network break cannot see other nodes

Tags: elasticsearch, failover

We are currently doing failover tests on our ElasticSearch setup. So here is the setup we use:

We have 4 ElasticSearch machines running. Let's name them ES1, ES2, ES3 and ES4.
We have some indexes on them with 5 shards each and 1 replica so 10 shards by indexes. Everything is well distributed on each nodes so if one node fail, everything will still be working.

The 4 nodes are on Windows 7 64 bits with 8GB of RAM. The nodes discover each other with the cluster name.

I unplug the ES1 machine to see if everything is still working fine, everything does, hurray!

But now here is the strange, we plug the ES1 again and this one doesn't go back on the cluster (named wc2014 FYI). He appears to be alone in a cluster named wc2014 too.

Here is some informations I've found in the logs:

When we unplugged (which seems normal to me)

```
org.elasticsearch.transport.NodeDisconnectedException: [IPDIRECTOR-119][inet[/10.194.1.119:9300]][cluster:monitor/nodes/info[n]] disconnected
[2015-08-12 11:27:04,619][DEBUG][action.admin.indices.stats] [IPDIRECTOR-118] [wc2014_nearline][4], node[fxTcr9-FR52jecm5a2adRg], [P], s[STARTED]: failed to execute [org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.stats.IndicesStatsRequest@1b999e6c]
org.elasticsearch.transport.NodeDisconnectedException: [IPDIRECTOR-119][inet[/10.194.1.119:9300]][indices:monitor/stats[s]] disconnected
[2015-08-12 11:27:04,619][DEBUG][action.admin.indices.stats] [IPDIRECTOR-118] [wc2014_mediaresource][4], node[fxTcr9-FR52jecm5a2adRg], [P], s[STARTED]: failed to execute [org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.stats.IndicesStatsRequest@1b999e6c]
org.elasticsearch.transport.NodeDisconnectedException: [IPDIRECTOR-119][inet[/10.194.1.119:9300]][indices:monitor/stats[s]] disconnected
[2015-08-12 11:27:04,619][DEBUG][action.admin.indices.stats] [IPDIRECTOR-118] [wc2014_edit][4], node[fxTcr9-FR52jecm5a2adRg], [P], s[STARTED]: failed to execute [org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.stats.IndicesStatsRequest@1b999e6c]
org.elasticsearch.transport.NodeDisconnectedException: [IPDIRECTOR-119][inet[/10.194.1.119:9300]][indices:monitor/stats[s]] disconnected
[2015-08-12 11:27:04,619][DEBUG][action.admin.indices.stats] [IPDIRECTOR-118] [wc2014_log][4], node[fxTcr9-FR52jecm5a2adRg], [P], s[STARTED]: failed to execute [org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.stats.IndicesStatsRequest@1b999e6c]
org.elasticsearch.transport.NodeDisconnectedException: [IPDIRECTOR-119][inet[/10.194.1.119:9300]][indices:monitor/stats[s]] disconnected
[2015-08-12 11:27:04,619][DEBUG][action.admin.indices.stats] [IPDIRECTOR-118] [wc2014_metadata][4], node[fxTcr9-FR52jecm5a2adRg], [R], s[STARTED]: failed to execute [org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.stats.IndicesStatsRequest@1b999e6c]
org.elasticsearch.transport.NodeDisconnectedException: [IPDIRECTOR-119][inet[/10.194.1.119:9300]][indices:monitor/stats[s]] disconnected
[2015-08-12 11:27:04,619][DEBUG][action.admin.indices.stats] [IPDIRECTOR-118] [wc2014_ipwsedit][4], node[fxTcr9-FR52jecm5a2adRg], [P], s[STARTED]: failed to execute [org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.stats.IndicesStatsRequest@1b999e6c]
```

Then I have differents errors looking like that:

```
[2015-08-12 11:27:09,797][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.node.info] [IPDIRECTOR-118] failed to execute on node [fxTcr9-FR52jecm5a2adRg]
org.elasticsearch.transport.SendRequestTransportException: [IPDIRECTOR-119][inet[/10.194.1.119:9300]][cluster:monitor/nodes/info[n]]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.sendRequest(TransportService.java:286)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesOperationAction$AsyncAction.start(TransportNodesOperationAction.java:165)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesOperationAction$AsyncAction.access$300(TransportNodesOperationAction.java:97)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesOperationAction.doExecute(TransportNodesOperationAction.java:70)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesOperationAction.doExecute(TransportNodesOperationAction.java:43)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:75)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClusterAdminClient.execute(NodeClusterAdminClient.java:77)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.FilterClient$ClusterAdmin.execute(FilterClient.java:161)
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.BaseRestHandler$HeadersAndContextCopyClient$ClusterAdmin.execute(BaseRestHandler.java:125)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClusterAdminClient.nodesInfo(AbstractClusterAdminClient.java:187)
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.action.admin.cluster.node.info.RestNodesInfoAction.handleRequest(RestNodesInfoAction.java:102)
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.BaseRestHandler.handleRequest(BaseRestHandler.java:53)
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.executeHandler(RestController.java:225)
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.dispatchRequest(RestController.java:170)
    at org.elasticsearch.http.HttpServer.internalDispatchRequest(HttpServer.java:121)
    at org.elasticsearch.http.HttpServer$Dispatcher.dispatchRequest(HttpServer.java:83)
    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty.NettyHttpServerTransport.dispatchRequest(NettyHttpServerTransport.java:329)
    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty.HttpRequestHandler.messageReceived(HttpRequestHandler.java:63)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty.pipelining.HttpPipeliningHandler.messageReceived(HttpPipeliningHandler.java:60)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:88)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentEncoder.messageReceived(HttpContentEncoder.java:82)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:88)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpChunkAggregator.messageReceived(HttpChunkAggregator.java:145)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecoder.messageReceived(HttpContentDecoder.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:459)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:536)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:435)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(OpenChannelsHandler.java:74)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.transport.NodeNotConnectedException: [IPDIRECTOR-119][inet[/10.194.1.119:9300]] Node not connected
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.nodeChannel(NettyTransport.java:936)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.sendRequest(NettyTransport.java:629)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.sendRequest(TransportService.java:276)
    ... 58 more
```

When we plug back in the node:

```
[2015-08-12 11:39:59,177][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [IPDIRECTOR-118] added {[IPDIRECTOR-119][3kybxeb7TMm30Pzh7rrmhA][Ipdirector-119][inet[/10.194.1.119:9300]],}, reason: zen-disco-receive(from master [[IPDIRECTOR-121][BX8BT6OgRjWM5YEhlxt9mQ][Ipdirector-121][inet[/10.194.1.121:9300]]])
[2015-08-12 11:48:07,768][INFO ][discovery.zen            ] [IPDIRECTOR-118] master_left [[IPDIRECTOR-121][BX8BT6OgRjWM5YEhlxt9mQ][Ipdirector-121][inet[/10.194.1.121:9300]]], reason [transport disconnected]
[2015-08-12 11:48:07,769][WARN ][discovery.zen            ] [IPDIRECTOR-118] master left (reason = transport disconnected), current nodes: {[IPDIRECTOR-118][Z9UA4kJxTIa6B3tY4F-_vw][Ipdirector-118][inet[/10.194.1.118:9300]],[IPDIRECTOR-119][3kybxeb7TMm30Pzh7rrmhA][Ipdirector-119][inet[/10.194.1.119:9300]],[IPDIRECTOR-120][EQzx7BprQa6EVOT3V6zlqQ][Ipdirector-120][inet[/10.194.1.120:9300]],}
[2015-08-12 11:48:07,769][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [IPDIRECTOR-118] removed {[IPDIRECTOR-121][BX8BT6OgRjWM5YEhlxt9mQ][Ipdirector-121][inet[/10.194.1.121:9300]],}, reason: zen-disco-master_failed ([IPDIRECTOR-121][BX8BT6OgRjWM5YEhlxt9mQ][Ipdirector-121][inet[/10.194.1.121:9300]])
[2015-08-12 11:48:11,541][WARN ][discovery.zen.ping.unicast] [IPDIRECTOR-118] failed to send ping to [[IPDIRECTOR-119][3kybxeb7TMm30Pzh7rrmhA][Ipdirector-119][inet[/10.194.1.119:9300]]]
org.elasticsearch.transport.ReceiveTimeoutTransportException: [IPDIRECTOR-119][inet[/10.194.1.119:9300]][internal:discovery/zen/unicast] request_id [124460] timed out after [3750ms]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$TimeoutHandler.run(TransportService.java:529)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[2015-08-12 11:48:11,541][WARN ][discovery.zen.ping.unicast] [IPDIRECTOR-118] failed to send ping to [[IPDIRECTOR-120][EQzx7BprQa6EVOT3V6zlqQ][Ipdirector-120][inet[/10.194.1.120:9300]]]
org.elasticsearch.transport.ReceiveTimeoutTransportException: [IPDIRECTOR-120][inet[/10.194.1.120:9300]][internal:discovery/zen/unicast] request_id [124461] timed out after [3750ms]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$TimeoutHandler.run(TransportService.java:529)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Some more timeouts and then a lot of this error:

```
[2015-08-12 11:48:26,677][WARN ][gateway.local            ] [IPDIRECTOR-118] [wc2014_clip][4]: failed to list shard stores on node [EQzx7BprQa6EVOT3V6zlqQ]
org.elasticsearch.action.FailedNodeException: Failed node [EQzx7BprQa6EVOT3V6zlqQ]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesOperationAction$AsyncAction.onFailure(TransportNodesOperationAction.java:206)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesOperationAction$AsyncAction.access$1000(TransportNodesOperationAction.java:97)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesOperationAction$AsyncAction$4.handleException(TransportNodesOperationAction.java:178)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$Adapter$3.run(TransportService.java:468)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.transport.NodeDisconnectedException: [IPDIRECTOR-120][inet[/10.194.1.120:9300]][internal:cluster/nodes/indices/shard/store[n]] disconnected
[2015-08-12 11:48:26,677][WARN ][gateway.local            ] [IPDIRECTOR-118] [wc2014_clip][4]: failed to list shard stores on node [3kybxeb7TMm30Pzh7rrmhA]
org.elasticsearch.action.FailedNodeException: Failed node [3kybxeb7TMm30Pzh7rrmhA]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesOperationAction$AsyncAction.onFailure(TransportNodesOperationAction.java:206)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesOperationAction$AsyncAction.access$1000(TransportNodesOperationAction.java:97)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesOperationAction$AsyncAction$4.handleException(TransportNodesOperationAction.java:178)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$Adapter$3.run(TransportService.java:468)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.transport.NodeDisconnectedException: [IPDIRECTOR-119][inet[/10.194.1.119:9300]][internal:cluster/nodes/indices/shard/store[n]] disconnected
[2015-08-12 11:48:27,081][WARN ][gateway.local            ] [IPDIRECTOR-118] [wc2014_clip][3]: failed to list shard stores on node [EQzx7BprQa6EVOT3V6zlqQ]
org.elasticsearch.action.FailedNodeException: Failed node [EQzx7BprQa6EVOT3V6zlqQ]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesOperationAction$AsyncAction.onFailure(TransportNodesOperationAction.java:206)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesOperationAction$AsyncAction.access$1000(TransportNodesOperationAction.java:97)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesOperationAction$AsyncAction$4.handleException(TransportNodesOperationAction.java:178)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$3.run(TransportService.java:290)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.transport.SendRequestTransportException: [IPDIRECTOR-120][inet[/10.194.1.120:9300]][internal:cluster/nodes/indices/shard/store[n]]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.sendRequest(TransportService.java:286)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesOperationAction$AsyncAction.start(TransportNodesOperationAction.java:165)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesOperationAction$AsyncAction.access$300(TransportNodesOperationAction.java:97)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesOperationAction.doExecute(TransportNodesOperationAction.java:70)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesOperationAction.doExecute(TransportNodesOperationAction.java:43)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:75)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:55)
    at org.elasticsearch.indices.store.TransportNodesListShardStoreMetaData.list(TransportNodesListShardStoreMetaData.java:79)
    at org.elasticsearch.gateway.local.LocalGatewayAllocator.buildShardStores(LocalGatewayAllocator.java:458)
    at org.elasticsearch.gateway.local.LocalGatewayAllocator.allocateUnassigned(LocalGatewayAllocator.java:292)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.routing.allocation.allocator.ShardsAllocators.allocateUnassigned(ShardsAllocators.java:74)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.routing.allocation.AllocationService.reroute(AllocationService.java:219)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.routing.allocation.AllocationService.reroute(AllocationService.java:162)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.routing.allocation.AllocationService.reroute(AllocationService.java:148)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery$3.execute(ZenDiscovery.java:387)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$UpdateTask.run(InternalClusterService.java:365)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.runAndClean(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:188)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:158)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.transport.NodeNotConnectedException: [IPDIRECTOR-120][inet[/10.194.1.120:9300]] Node not connected
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.nodeChannel(NettyTransport.java:936)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.sendRequest(NettyTransport.java:629)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.sendRequest(TransportService.java:276)
```

If I want to resolve this, I have to manually restart the node and then everything go back to normal.

Shouldnt the node automatically talks back to ES2, 3, 4 and get back in the cluster together without me having to do some manual operations on it?

Thanks,
Matthias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so we have the solution to the problem we encountered. We have 4 ElasticSearch machines but only one was set in master node so when the network shutdown happend, 2 clusters started to live side by side.

Answer (score 0):

Check the elesticsearch.yml file

```
/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
```

You'll want to verify that the discovery type matches the environment that you are running in ex ec2.

Comment: Sorry, I added some details with your answer. We're running ElasticSearch on Windows 7 64 bits machines. And we have set auto discovery because it's what discover them when I start/restart the nodes manually.

And we let the config by default for the discovery type in the config YML.